# IGMPv2 flood source detection

Tags: linux, networking

In wireshark I can see `Membership Query, general` IGMPv2 requests coming over and over from 0.0.0.0 source which suggests ( according to [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3376) ) machine that hasn't received address yet. My question is how in Linux environment I can find such machine. This query triggers many answers and causes significant network communication slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

When a machine is connected to a network for the first time, it will try to find the DHCP servers in order to get an IP address configuration. Untill then, as you already said, it has no IP address and the only identifier it has is it's MAC address, which is used to keep a comunication alive while it negotiates with the DHCP server (during this period it does not have an IP address until the very last).

Answering your question, you'd find the machine you are looking for making use of the MAC address. If you are on a small network, a manual check (`ifconfig`) will do it but, if you are on a big one, you better check the ARP table of your switch(es) to have a better idea where it could be.